# How to change the default padding for "th" on foundation mail framework? using scss

Tags: css, email, sass, zurb-foundation

In foundation mail framework each "th" element has a default padding. In the HTML it looks like this:

```
padding-bottom: 16px;
padding-left: 16px;
padding-right: 16px;
```

How to change it in the framework? Changing $global-padding in settings.scss doesn't help

Comment: Why not just use `th { padding: 0 }`?

Answer (score 1):

you car create a **scss file: foundation-overwrite.scss** and reset what you whant there, you can reset any others classes in the future if u need and not mess with the framework.

so include:

```
th { padding: 0 }
```

or change the variable but again using the new file you created. not the framework one.

```
/// Default padding for table.
/// @type Number
$table-padding: rem-calc(8 10 10) !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$table-padding` variable. Source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/scss/components/_table.scss).

Comment: This is only true for "Foundation for Sites". He is asking about the email framework "Foundation for Emails".